# Slack OAuth v2 does not return private channels

Tags: slack-api

We are rebuilding our Slack APP using the new oAuth v2. The issue with v2 is that the **conversations.list** API only returns public channels, not private channels.

The scope we set is: **channels:read,groups:read,mpim:read,chat:write,usergroups:read**

The API method is : **https://slack.com/api/conversations.list?type=public_channel,private_channel,mpim**

Everything works with v1. But when we use a token granted by the v2 Oauth, the conversations.list only returns public channel. I suspect it is a problem with the scope, but its doc says that the usergroups:read is the right scope for getting private channels.

Has anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Anwser: use the user token staring with xoxp instead of bot token starting with xoxb. With Oauth v2, the user token is in [authed_user][access_token], and the bot token is returned directly as [access_token] in the json response.

Answer (score 0):

@lee-li is correct and pointed me in the right direction.

The Bot token seems to only access public channels whereas the User token lists the private channels as well.

Following this link: https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list

I added the following User scopes:

- channels:read
- groups:read
- im:read
- mpimp:read

Then I reinstalled the App on the workspace and grabbed the new User Token (with xoxp...) to use in my app.

Boom! Private channels!